# error TS2769: No overload matches this call. when implementing a model in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am running into an error when implementing a model in angular:

the component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DamageAssessmentReportService } from 'src/app/damage-assessment-report.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Report } from 'src/app/models/report.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fa-daform',
  templateUrl: './fa-daform.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fa-daform.component.css']
})
export class FADAFormComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private damageAssessmentReportService : DamageAssessmentReportService, private router: Router) { }

  createDamageAssessmentReport(assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateString: string){

    const reportDateTime = new Date(reportDateString);
    this.damageAssessmentReportService.createDAReport(assessmentDescription,author, reportDateTime).subscribe((report : Report)=>{
      console.log(report);
      //navigate to /damageAssessments/damageAssessments._id
      this.router.navigate(['/detailed-daforms', report._id])
  })
  }

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  }
```

and the model.ts:

```
export class Report{
    _id: string ="";
    assessmentDescription: string = "";
    author: string = "";
    reportDateTime: Date = new Date("");
}
```

The error presented:

> error TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3,
> '(observer?: Partial<Observer> | undefined): Subscription',
> gave the following error.
> Type '(report: Report) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer>'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value:
> Object) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(report: Report) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'report' and 'value' are incompatible.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Report': _id, assessmentDescription, author, reportDateTime
> Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null |
> undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined,
> complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(report: Report) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'report' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Report'.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
>
> 22
> this.damageAssessmentReportService.createDAReport(assessmentDescription,author,
> reportDateTime).subscribe((report : Report)=>{
>
> ```
>                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> × Failed to compile.

createDAReport method from DamageAssessmentReportService

```
createDAReport(assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateTime: Date){
    //send web req to create DA report
    return this.webReqService.post('DamageAssessments', {assessmentDescription, author, reportDateTime})
  }
```

webReqService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebRequestService {

  readonly ROOT_URL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.ROOT_URL= 'http://localhost:3000';
  }
  
  get(uri: string) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`)
  }
```

post(uri: string, payload: Object) {
return this.http.post(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
}

patch(uri: string, payload: Object) {
return this.http.patch(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
}

delete(uri: string) {
return this.http.delete(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`);
}

}

Comment: Can you show this `createDAReport` method from `DamageAssessmentReportService`?

Comment: Hey yeah just updated

Comment: Hi, just double confirm is `webReqService` instance of `HttpClient`? As what you did in the constructor, `constructor(private webReqService: HttpClient)`

Comment: Yes it is ill update it with the webReqServices

Comment: I think the problem here, as i see the error, is that angular tries to map the response from createDAReport method to a Report object. Try to use any instead of Report like this: this.damageAssessmentReportService.creatteDAReport(assessmentDescription,author, reportDateTime). subscribe ((report: any) => ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the existing code and error message, as you want to get the Observable of `T`, would suggest you use Overload #15 for [Angular - HttpClient (Post)](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) by specifying the `T` type.

```js
post<T>(url: string, body: any, options?: { headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; context?: HttpContext; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | number | boolean | readonly (string | ... 1 more ... | boolean)[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }): Observable<T>
```

> WebRequestService

You can do similar as what [Angular handle for HttpClient methods](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L2552), by using function overloading.

```js
post<T>(uri: string, payload: Object): Observable<T>;
post(uri: string, payload: Object): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`, payload);
}
```

> DamageAssessmentReportService

```js
createDAReport(assessmentDescription: string, author: string, reportDateTime: Date): Observable<Report>{
  //send web req to create DA report
  return this.webReqService.post<Report>('DamageAssessments', {assessmentDescription, author, reportDateTime})
}
```